# Volume of Revolution (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

This is one of the question I got for my Calculus midterm. I had it a few days ago and I still don't know the answer so I am hoping some calculus geniuses on this site can help me figure it out.

Q: Let R be the region below the function $f(x) = e^{-2x^2-2x}$ and above the x-axis for $1 \le x \le 4$. Find the volume of the solid obtained by fully revolving R about the line $x=-1$.

I attempted shell method:

$$V = \int_1^2 2\pi (x+1) e^{-2x^2-2x} dx$$

But then I don't know how to integrate this. So I tried using cylinder method by finding the inverse of $f(x)$. After interchanging $x$ and $y$ and simplifying it, I got:

$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{\sqrt{1-\ln(x^2)}-1}{2}$$ (Tell me if I am wrong.)

Therefore,

$$V = \int_{e^{-24}}^{e^-4} \pi \left[\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-\ln(x^2)}-1}{2} + 1\right)^2 -1\right]dx$$

which I also don't know how to integrate.

Can anyone please show me how to integrate any of these two? Or if I am approaching this problem incorrectly, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: The integral can be represented by elementary functions if $f(x)=e^{-x^2-2x}$.

Comment: I'm sure it wasn't that. Or else I would've gotten the question right cuz thats just simple u-substitution.

Comment: WolframAlpha gives: $$\int_1^4 (x+1)e^{-2x^2-x}dx=\frac{e^{81/2}\sqrt{2\pi}\left(\text{erf}\left(\frac 9{\sqrt2}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac 3{\sqrt2}\right)\right)-2+2e^{36}}{8e^{40}}.$$

Where $\text{erf}(\cdot)$ is the error function (not elementary).

Comment: I'd say it's a mistake in the question. $e^{-(x^2+2x)}$ makes so much more sense